# ¿Cómo borrar todos los directorios que están ubicados dentro en un directorio con C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tengo una carpeta que se llama `Archivos`, en ella, varias carpetas, `carpeta_1`, `carpeta_dos`, etc, lo que deseo, es borrar todos las carpetas y archivos que se encuentran en la carpeta Archivos, sin borrar esta misma(`Archivos`).

Si uso esto, me borrar solo los archivos, pero no las carpetas que están dentro de `Archivos`

```
var file = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("/Archivos/"), subdirectorio );
System.IO.File.Delete(file);
```

Si uso este de abajo, me dice que no encuetra la ruta:

```
System.IO.Directory.Delete(Server.MapPath("~/" + subdirectorio + msg.Attachments[0].Name), true);
```

me gustaría saber como poder hacerlo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Haces un `foreach` del directorio padre, leyendo los archivos y los directorios y los eliminas.

```
System.IO.DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("Archivos");

foreach (FileInfo file in di.GetFiles())
{
    file.Delete(); 
}
foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in di.GetDirectories())
{
    dir.Delete(true); 
}
```